# New representation of annihilation operator in tight binding model for graphene

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, second-quantization, graphene, tight-binding

In [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1163v2) about the electronic properties of graphene, in section b the author considers the usual tight binding hamiltonian for graphene
$$ H=-t\sum_{<i,j>,\sigma}(a_{\sigma,i}^{\dagger} b_{\sigma,j}+h.c.) $$

and then writes down in eq.(16) the usual Fourier transform of the fermion operator $a_{n}$ (which destroys an electron on site n of the sub lattice A):

$$ a_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k} e^{(-ik\cdot r_{n})}  a(k)$$

The he says, referring to this previous transformation:

> Using this transformation, let us write the field $a_{n}$ as a sum of two terms coming from expanding the Fourier sum around $\textbf{K}$ and $\textbf{K'}$.

These points in momentum space ($\textbf{K}$ and $\textbf{K'}$) he is referring to are the usual inequivalent Dirac points of graphene.
Then he continues by saying:

> This produces an approximation for the representation of the field $a_{n}$ as a sum of two new fields, written as  $$ a_{n}\approx e^{(-i \textbf{K}\cdot r_{n})} a_{1,n}+ e^{(-i \textbf{K'}\cdot r_{n})} a_{2,n} $$ where the index 1,2 refers to the $\textbf{K}$,$\textbf{K'}$ point.

Now, I don't understand how this last equation is derived starting from the first one. How do you mathematically get there?

Also, what is the physical meaning of the new operators $a_{1,2}$?
Is it correct to say that these are just like the original operator $a(k)$ but centered in different momentum points (i.e.the two Dirac points $\textbf{K}$,$\textbf{K'}$)? So that for example $a_{1}(k)$ is equal to $a(\textbf{K}+k)$?

Besides this observation in momentum space, I don't understand what is the difference between the operator $a$ and $a_{1,2}$ in real space. Don't they act in the same way (in real space) by annihilating the electron from a specific lattice site?